# Why does Git think Vi quit in error?

Tags: git

Is there anything wrong with opening up a new vim tab (for scratch work) while authoring a git commit?

## Update: This Seems to Be a Quirk With Vi vs. Vim

On further inspection prompted by [@muru](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/205/muru)'s comment, it seems there are a couple of subtleties here.

1. The `EDITOR` environment variable was actually unset, so it defaulted to `vi` instead of `vim` as originally posted. Edited.
2. In order for vi to exit with error, it is actually important to *attempt to quit first* with `:q` before using `:q!`, and this behavior can be reproduced without using tabs:

   1. Launch vi:
      `vi; echo $?`
   2. Type something in insert mode
   3. Attempt to quit with `:q` and get the error `E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)`
   4. Actually quit with `:q!`
   5. Observe that the exit code is `1`
3. Oddly enough, modifying the above steps by (1) using vim instead of vi, or (2) using vi but quitting with `:q!` directly without using `:q` first, yields a `0` exit code instead. Both `vi` and `vim` have the same exact `:version` string on my system, so this is probably a difference in how vim behaves when started as `vi` on the command-line.

## Original Steps with Git + Vi

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start making a new commit:

   ```
   $ export EDITOR=vi  # goes without saying :)
   $ git commit
   ```
2. Open up a new tab with `:tabe` and type something. Anything.
3. Switch back to the commit tab with `gt`.
4. Type some message, and close the commit tab with `:x` (writing changes).
5. Now, attempt to quit the tab with `:q`.
6. Now, quit the scratch tab with `:q!` (discarding changes).
7. Recoil as vi tells you your meticulously-crafted commit message has *also* been discarded:

   ```
   error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
   Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
   ```

*What is Git not happy with in this seemingly innocuous series of steps?*

**(This gets confusing because I'm testing Vim's behavior, not Vi's)**

Vim's exit code indicates success when repeating the above instructions, so it's not clear why Git thinks Vim quit in error:

```
$ vim a-file; echo "exit code: $?"
exit code: 0
```

> ^ This example is identical to how Git launches Vim, given its process entry in that state:
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/vi /path/to/git/repo/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
> ```

Also, swapping the tab exit order by closing the scratch tab first, then the commit tab, has exactly the same result.

Coming back to the million-dollar question—why is this happening? Answers in the form of snarky references to the Vim/Git docs are most welcome

---

**System:** macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
**vim :version:** `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Nov 29 2017 18:37:46)`
**git --version:** `git version 2.15.1 (Apple Git-101)`

Comment: when you are inside vim during these steps, are you sure `:version` actually shows 8.0.1283?

Comment: Good question @Mass, yes it does. I pulled the vim version text from the blank page at first, and edited the port with the output of `:version`. It is the same when vim is invoked from git, and directly.

Comment: Why is git talking about `vi` when `vim` is the editor? Do you have other configuration overriding the `EDITOR` variable? Maybe `$VISUAL`, or some git config settings?

Comment: Thanks a lot @muru, you've pointed out what was causing the difference in observed behavior. I went back to check and found out that Vim behaves differently from Vi specifically with its exit code, and that to reproduce it you need to try `:q` before `:q!`